# Split off logic in methods when custom Comparator is provided or elements implements Comparable?

Tags: java, collections, comparator, comparable

What is The best practice to split off logic in methods , who will work with Comparable elements, or specific Comparator is provided at creation time, depending on which constructor of the class is used?
Example:

```
public class MinMax<E> {

private final Comparator<? super E> comparator;
private final boolean isSpecificComparatorProvided;

public MinMax() {
    this.comparator = null;
    this.isSpecificComparatorProvided = false;
    ........;
}

public MinMax(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
    this.comparator = comparator;
    this.isSpecificComparatorProvided = true;
    ........;
}

private boolean isBigOrEqual(E e1, E e2) {
    if (isSpecificComparatorProvided) {
        Comparator<? super E> cpr = comparator;
        int cmpr = cpr.compare(e1, e2);
        return cmpr > -1;
    } else {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Comparable<? super E> e1Comparable = (Comparable<? super E>) e1;
        int cmprTo = e1Comparable.compareTo(e2);
        return cmprTo > -1;
    }
}

}
```

Do I have allways check for specific comparator in method isBigOrEqual()?
Also is the cast to Comparable needed when NO specific Comparator is provided?
Is there a other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest way of dealing with this is to only implement the case for a `Comparator`, and then when you're not passed a `Comparator`, write one that just works on `Comparable`.  (In Java 8, this is just Comparator.naturalOrder().)

```
new Comparator<T> {
  @Override public int compare(T a, T b) {
    return a.compareTo(b);
  }
};
```

`TreeMap` doesn't do this for performance reasons, but it's simpler to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could restrict `E` to be comparable similar to `public class MinMax<E extends Comparable<E>>` so the cast is not necessary any more as `E` has to be comparable at compile time:

```
public class MinMax<E extends Comparable<E>> {

    private final Comparator<? super E> comparator;

    private final boolean isSpecificComparatorProvided;

    public MinMax() {
        this.comparator = null;
        this.isSpecificComparatorProvided = false;
    }

    public MinMax(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
        this.isSpecificComparatorProvided = true;
    }

    private boolean isBigOrEqual(E e1, E e2) {
        if (this.isSpecificComparatorProvided) {
            return this.comparator.compare(e1, e2) > -1;
        } else {
            return e1.compareTo(e2) > -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This Answer seems usefull to me. I want ask, as i understand , there will be no problem at run time if  E is not implement Comparable , but specific Comparator is provided , right ?

Comment: No. There will be a compile error if E doesn't implement Comparable.

Comment: If you are not sure whether `E` will implement `Comparable` or not, even your code will fail nonetheless, because you cast to `Comparable`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you want to abstract a way of comparing two objects of type E and there are two implementations. One uses a specific `Comparator`, while the other deals with `Comparable` objects. So you can split those two behaviours into separate classes (implementations).

Let's start with an interface for our abstract concept:

```
interface AbstractComparer<E> {
    public boolean isBigOrEqual(E e1, E e2);
}
```

Sorry for the uninspired name.

Next, let's implement the case which deals with Comparable objects:

```
class ComparableComparer<E extends Comparable<E>> implements AbstractComparer<E> {

    @Override
    public boolean isBigOrEqual(E e1, E e2) {
        return e1.compareTo(e2) > -1;
    }

}
```

The implementation for the other case receives the specific comparator via a constructor:

```
class ComparatorComparer<E> implements AbstractComparer<E> {

    private Comparator<E> comparator;

    public ComparatorComparer(Comparator<E> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBigOrEqual(E e1, E e2) {
        return this.comparator.compare(e1, e2) > -1;
    }
}
```

Now, we can simplify the `MinMax` class and we can provide the comparing method via a constructor:

```
public class MinMax<E> {

    private final AbstractComparer<E> comparer;

    public MinMax(AbstractComparer<E> comparer) {
        this.comparer = comparer;
    }

    private boolean isBigOrEqual(E e1, E e2) {
        return comparer.isBigOrEqual(e1, e2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very Nice solution. I thought that I would find the best practice looking at source code of well known classes from java collection framework, for example TreeMap<K,V> , but i can not figure it out , because of large size of code. For the key K in  TreeMap<K,V> the situation is just like in my case, Two constructors - one for  using the natural ordering of keys and All keys inserted into the map must implement the Comparable interface. And second constructor for the case when Comparator is provided.

Comment: It's debatable which approach is better. With my approach it's clearer and safer because you avoid using non-`Comparable` objects without a specified `Comparator`. And you don't have to pepper your code with `comparator == null` checks everywhere. But if TreeMap was implemented the way I did it, then the user of TreeMap will have to always provide a AbstractComparer object, which would be quite annoying. So you'll have to decide which approach is better for your needs.